# Writing a Shell Function that accepts input from a pipe and arguments simultaneously

Tags: linux, function, pipe, stdin, ksh

I'm trying to write a function that I call `logAction` specifically for `Ksh` that reads input from a pipe and accepts arguments in the same function call. I've been trying to debug this for 2 weeks searching on Google and sites like this.

The purpose of the function that I'm trying to create is to simplify the process of logging output to a log file for other scripts that I've developed. I intend to use the command for a variety of situations, but the 2 easiest to describe and illustrate what I'm attempting are similar to the following:

Syntax Example 1:

```
logAction 1 "Script executed some action."
```

Syntax Example 2:

```
COMMAND1 | COMMAND2 | logAction 1
```

As you can see, I want to be able to pass the intended log information to the function either as an argument or as stdinput through a pipe in order to capture the output of a command sequence.  A 3rd scenario would be to prepend some text before the piped output, i.e.

Syntax Example 3:

```
COMMAND1 | COMMAND2 | logAction 1 "This is the output:  "
```

The output below illustrates what the result would be from using the syntax in Example 3:

```
[2015/12/28 10:20:32] This is the output:  <Output from COMMAND1 | COMMAND 2>
```

Here's a basic skeleton of the function I'm trying to create.

```
function logAction {
  while read -t 0 -u 0 stdinput
  do
    echo "StdInput:'$stdinput'"
    pipedinput=$stdinput
  done
  pipedinput=${pipedinput:-}

  case $1 in
    1)  #Output text only to log file
        output=$(echo "$pretag ${@:2} $pipedinput")
        echo $output >> $LOG
    2)  #Output text to screen and log file
        output=$(echo "$pretag ${@:2} $pipedinput")
        echo $output
        echo $output >> $LOG
    3)  
        ....
  esac
  unset pipedinput
}
```

Originally, I didn't supply the `-t` argument to the `read` command, and the function would pause execution until the user entered `CTRL-D` to indicate `EOF`. However, for my purposes, this function is intended to have silent operation and should not request user input.  Adding the `-t 0` argument with the `read` command tells the read command to timeout with 0 seconds instead of waiting for `EOF` from the keyboard.

This solved the problem for some cases; however, the `read` command doesn't capture any input when used with the `cat` command like so:

```
cat somefile.txt | logAction 1
cat somefile.txt | awk '{ a=a" "$1 }END{ print a }' | logAction 1
```

Yet using `echo` seems to work:

```
echo "ab bc cd de ef fg gh" | logAction 1 "This is the output: "
```

I have been able to make it work with `cat` by changing the 0 for the timeout to 0.1 (i.e. `read -t 0.1`), but I'm concerned that this is a dirty solution. This seems to indicate there is a race condition where the `read` command is being executed before the pipe has finished its output and closed. This wasn't what I expected, as I thought the preceding command in a pipe sequence must finish execution before the subsequent command is executed.

Is there a way to tell the `read` command to ignore stdin from the keyboard and use the stdout from the preceeding command in the pipe? I tried to tell it to use `FD0` (which I thought was the stdout from the pipe, but it seems to also be connected to the keyboard) with the the `-u 0` argument, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function log 
{
    ARG1=$1
    ARG2=$2

    if [ ! -t 0 ] 
    then
        INPUT=$(cat)
    else
        INPUT=""
    fi  

    echo "<datetime>" ${ARG2}${INPUT}
}

log 1 "Script executed some action."

echo "<data from pipe>" | log 2 "this is the output: "

echo "<data from pipe>" | cat | log 2 "this is the output: "
```

Output:

```
<datetime> Script executed some action.
<datetime> this is the output: <data from pipe>
<datetime> this is the output: <data from pipe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ziffusion. This seems to work. I've ran across this trick before using `cat`; however, I didn't use it because I thought I read somewhere where this may encounter a race condition or have other vulnerabilities.  It seems preferable that there would be a builtin command for this function versus this trickery with `cat`. Still, I've tested it with my code and it seems to work right now. I am still curious why `read` doesn't work in my example.  How is it that the shell is executing the `read` timeout param before the prior commands in the pipe are finished executing?

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work. A timeout of `0` causes `read` to return immediately.

Comment: I understand that a timeout of `0` should cause `read` to return immediately; however, I thought that this would only occur once the previous command in the pipe finished and the output was fed to the function call that contains `read`.  Correct me if I am wrong, but if I construct a pipe like `CMD1 | CMD2 | MyFunction`, doesn't the function only get executed once CMD2 has finished? Shouldn't the output of CMD2 be immediately available to the function, such that a timeout of `0` for the `read` command in `MyFunction` still captures input?

Comment: `CMD1`, `CMD2`, and `MyFunction` are executed by the `shell` in their own `processes`, in *parallel*. They begin execution virtually at the same time. Your name `MyFunction` is a bit of a misnomer because the way you are running it, it is a `process`. Although, a shell script *can* have functions within it (like my code does).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I guess I made the assumption the commands were executed sequentially because they seem to rely upon the output from the previous commands, but I can understand how the pipes could be setup and the processes will persist in parallel and process any output until the pipes are closed by the previous commands.

Comment: Correct. Pipes were meant to be primitives for plumbing *as well* as parallelism. Useful for long running pipelines that produce output continuously.